# error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std:

Tags: c++, gcc, stdvector

I write func to write strings from file to vector and have a error

```
error : error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(std::ifstream&)
```

**code:**

```
//parse file file

#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

const unsigned short numOfStrings=5;

void ReadFromFile (std::ifstream& thisin, std::vector<std::string>& thisData)
{
    thisData.push_back(thisin);
}

int main ()
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can't push an ifstream into a vector of strings.

Comment: You forgot to add a while loop in you function that reads in the strings from `thisin` and then you can add those strings into the vector.

Comment: See part 2 of this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/487892) on how to read a file line by line. You don't need the inner `std::istringstream iss(line); ...` part replace it with `thisData.push_back(line);`

Comment: Does `numOfStrings` play any part in this question?

Comment: no, forgot to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to push into the vector the `ifstream`, not reading from it.

To read from ifstream, you could have done the following.

```cpp
void ReadFromFile (std::ifstream& thisin, std::vector<std::string>& thisData)
{
    std::string word;
    while(thisin >> word)
    {
        thisData.push_back(word);
    } 
}
```